# Move Logo Position

Tags: magento2, theme, position, logo

I am new to using magento, and have currently extended the Luma theme and changed the logo to my own.

Currently the logo is in its default left position and I want to move it to the centre. I've been stuck on this for a while. Any help is appreciated.

I am using magento2.

Answer (score 2):

> app/design/frontend/Package/theme/Magento_Theme/layout/default.xml

```
<!-- Main Header -->
<container name="header.main" htmlTag="header" htmlClass="header-main">
    <container name="header.main.container" htmlTag="div" htmlClass="container">
        <container name="header.main.row" htmlTag="div" htmlClass="row vcenter">
            <container name="header.main.social" htmlTag="div" htmlClass="col-md-3 col-sm-3 hidden-xs header-social" before="-">
                <block name="header.social" class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" template="Magento_Theme::html/header/social.phtml"/>
            </container>
            <container name="mobile-toggle-wrapper" htmlTag="div" htmlClass="hidden-sm hidden-md hidden-lg col-xs-1">
                <block name="mobile-toggle" class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" template="Magento_Theme::html/header/mobile-toggle.phtml"/>
            </container>
            <container name="header.main.logo" htmlTag="div" htmlClass="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-10 header-logo">
                <block class="Magento\Theme\Block\Html\Header\Logo" name="logo">
                    <arguments>
                        <argument name="logo_img_width" xsi:type="number">499</argument>
                        <argument name="logo_img_height" xsi:type="number">57</argument>
                    </arguments>
                </block>
            </container>
            <container name="header.main.search" htmlTag="div" htmlClass="col-md-3 col-sm-3 header-search hidden-xs" after="-">
                <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" template="Magento_Search::form.mini.phtml" />
            </container>
        </container>
    </container>
</container>
<!-- End Main Header -->
```